# I see a " folder in the top level of the ubuntu 22.04 install - what is its purpose

Tags: 22.04

I do not see this on the Ubuntu 20.04 version install.  These are all installed on AWS with Apache.  I cannot remove this folder. When I CD /"/   I get a prompt >

Is this something that is unique to version 22.04?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should use quotes in pairs on your command lines. Otherwise `bash` will prompt you for a continuation line to "close" the quote.

Comment: I have added a screen shot to the post.

Comment: To go into the `"` directory you should use `cd '"'`

Comment: The `>` prompt comes from `$PS2` (`man bash`) and indicates that `bash` is waiting for you to complete the `"` quoted string you began. Type `Ctrl-C`. Also, Linux is case sensitive, so your command should be `cd /`, but you, at your current knowledge  level, probably shouldn't. Don't commit UTBLT! (Using Tool Before Learning Tool) (Using Thing Before Learning Thing).

Comment: You'll have to "escape" the quote with `\ `: `ls -l /\"`.

Comment: Or use a wilcard: `ls -l /?` matches all single character filenames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating files and directories whose names contain special characters like `"` may be somewhat difficult in command line. For example, the `"` character has a special meaning in command line and should be  [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-when-using-bash) using the sequence `\"` or putting it inside `'` like `'"'`. So, to refer to the directory you specified, `/\"` or `'/"'` may be used.

The directory you specified was probably created accidentally or by a faulty script. You can safely remove it using the command:

```
$ sudo rmdir /\"
```

However, if this directory is not empty, you will get an error message like

```
rmdir: failed to remove '/"': Directory not empty
```

and you should inspect its contents first by using the command:

```
$ sudo ls -al /\"
```

If you become absolutely sure that the contents of this directory are not of any interest to you, you can completely remove it together with its contents using the command:

```
$ sudo rmdir -fr /\"
```

**Please note that the last command is a very powerful one and it may completely erase your system if you mistype it!**

Comment: I  did use your suggestion and had to do the following:   sudo rm  -r /\"
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JackStein Upvoting the answer (clicking on the ✔️ mark on the left) is the usual way of acknowledging that the answer helps solve your problem.